# Xpath for a unique string in XML root element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XML format is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='stylesheet.xsl'?>
<!--

Test case ID: C:\Me\z\d\e\t\w.ts
Result Test:PASSED      
balbalbalbalbalbalbalbalbl
***********************************************************************************************/
-->
<Results IsFinished="No">
....
```

I am novice with XPath definition, and I would need a variable in stylesheet for the Test Case ID in the commented section above.

**My tryout for the variable looks like this:**

```
<xsl:param name="text" select="/"/>
<xsl:variablename="TestScript" select="substring-after($text, 'Test case ID:')"/>
```

...

This variable is later on used in a template:

```
<xsl:template name="test_name">


<xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'Test case ID:')">

                <xsl:call-template name="break_2">

                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$TestScript"/>

                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>
```

Though the value of variable won't show up later on when calling the template, neither could find a way to declare it **Globally** (as the tryout shown above, since locally works perfectly).

Locally declared in the template works:

```
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'Test case ID:')">
            <xsl:variable name="TestScript" select="substring-after($text, 'Test case ID:')"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="break_2">

                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$TestScript"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>


</xsl:template>
```

**How can I set that variable globally?**

Comment: Are you really trying to extract a substring from a comment?

Comment: Your title, and the `<xsl:param name="text" select="/"/>`, indicate that you're trying to match on a string that's in the content of an element descended from `/`. But elsewhere you seem to indicate you're trying to match on the contents of a comment.

Comment: Then how can I point to the comment section? I didn't found any selector for that "node". 
I must extract that path from comment, and I cannot change XML format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string you want to extract always is in the first comment of the document you can do:

```
<xsl:variablename="TestScript" select="substring-after(/comment()[1], 'Test case ID:')"/>
```

This will however give you everything in the comment after `Test Case ID:`

```
 C:\Me\z\d\e\t\w.ts
Result Test:PASSED      
balbalbalbalbalbalbalbalbl
***********************************************************************************************/
```

If you just want the ID, wrap it in another `substring-before` and `normalize-space` to strip the spaces and linebreak:

```
<xsl:variablename="TestScript" 
    select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(/comment()[1], 'Test case ID:'), 'Result'))"/>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Therefore I learnt that: 
I can point to a comment section simply by the comment() selector. 
[n] after it tells me that the first such hit of comment section will be selected. 
Also, I learnt how to wrap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get the test case id into a global variable, place this at the top of your stylesheet, outside of any template:

```
<xsl:variable name="caseID" select="substring-before(substring-after(/comment()[1], 'Test case ID: '), '&#10;')"/>
```

This will extract the substring between "Test case ID: " and the subsequent line feed from the first comment that is a child of the root node.

I am not sure how you're going to use this variable once you have it (your stylesheet is missing that part).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! This Case ID is in fact a test file path, the test script processed by a program and producing the output XML file we are discussing. My intention with this path variable is to link certain parts from the styled sheet to the original test script, making the browser to open it there (indirectly). In short: **Test Debugging Feature**